# My global variables are not working like i imagine they should

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Below is some code i am using to pull out some serial data from an arduino. This IF statement if (Ardinput == stagecode):  Is not using the global variable declared earlier in the same function. I know its something with my logic i just not sure what.

EDIT I added all my code to help clear things up

```
stagecode = "STAGE "

ser = serial.Serial(
port='COM3',
baudrate=9600, 
)



def stage():
            urllib.request.urlopen(url + 'f.stage')


def capture():
    global Ardinput
    print ("Start capture")



    while (1):           
            line = ser.readline()
            if (line != ""):
               print (line)
               Ardinput = line
               Ardinput = Ardinput.decode("utf-8")
               print (Ardinput + ' Befor CR')
               Ardinput = Ardinput[:-1]
               print (Ardinput)
               done = Ardinput
               break
if (Ardinput == stagecode):       
    print (stagecode + ' IN IF FUNCTION')
    #stage()

print ("Start Application" + Ardinput  )
print

capture()
```

Comment: Same function? Are you sure your indentation here is the same as in your code?

Comment: I think you actually have to execute `capture()` before the if statement.

Comment: You havn't assigned a default value or getting value in `stagecode` ?

Comment: @cambria, please do not change the very _nature_ of the question with edits, it makes the whole SO concept useless. You can add information but wholesale edits that make all answers to date not only wrong but sensless, is not the way to go. The _specific_ problem for this question is the indenting. If you fix that and there's still a problem, ask a new question. I've reverted this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ardinput` variable won't come into existence until you've called the `capture()` function and that's happening *after* the `if` statement.

What you have is equivalent to:

```
def fn():
    global xyzzy
    xyzzy = 42

print xyzzy
fn()
```

which will generate an error. You have to actually *call* `fn()` to create the variable, before you can use it.

The other possibility is that your `if` statement is supposed to be part of the `capture()` function itself, in which case you just have your indentation wrong.

As it stands, the `if` and `print` are *outside* of that function, hence executed before the variable comes into existence.

A good way to check why the `if` statement doesn't seem to be working, if you're sure it should be, is to put some temporary debug code in before the `if`, printing out the length and content of both variables:

```
print "%d:[%s] %d:[%s]" % (len(Ardinput), Ardinput, len(stagecode), stagecode)
```

That should hopefully show up any differences.

Comment: Sorry here is the lines that were omitted                                                             if (Ardinput == stagecode):       
        print (stagecode + ' IN IF FUNCTION')
        #stage()

print ("Start Application" + Ardinput  )
print

capture()

Comment: I see what you were saying about the if being outside for the block of function but i think i fixed that yet i am getting the same issue. any ideas?

Comment: @cambria, please do not change the very _nature_ of the question with edits, it makes the whole SO concept useless. The _specific_ problem for this question is the indenting. If you fix that and there's still a problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting the if statement to live inside the `capture()` function, but it doesn't because it is not indented.

Either way, you won't have access to the global `Ardinput` until after the `capture()` function is called. So unless you're calling the function before your if statement you'll get an error.